# How do you plot up until a condition is met using within polygon method in python?

Tags: python

I am stuck on a problem with plotting points on a scatter plot up until a condition is met. I am using the shapely python module to create a boolean condition. That is, if any point enters the polygon, plot. My goal is to plot the points on the scatter plot up until the point enters the polygon, then stop plotting. So points (10,10), (11,11), and (12,12) should not be plotted. I tried using 'break' and other conditions but I have been unsuccessful. Would you have any suggestions on how to resolve this?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import LineString, MultiLineString
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, Point


x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10, 11, 12, 13]
y = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10, 11, 12, 13]

polygon1 = Polygon([(8, 8), (8, 10), (10, 10), (10, 8)])
polygon2 = Polygon([(1,1), (1, 2), (2,2) ,(2,1)])
for p in range(len(x)):
    for i, j in zip(x,y):
        if np.any((Point(i,j).within(polygon1)) == True):
            plt.scatter(x,y)
            break
        
        
coord1 = [[8,8], [8,10], [10,10] ,[10,8]]
coord1.append(coord1[0])
xs, ys = zip(*coord1) #create lists of x and y values 
plt.plot(xs,ys)
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. I hope this helps.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import LineString, MultiLineString
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, Point


x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10, 11, 12, 13]
y = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10, 11, 12, 13]

polygon1 = Polygon([(8, 8), (8, 10), (10, 10), (10, 8)])
polygon2 = Polygon([(1,1), (1, 2), (2,2) ,(2,1)])
        
for i,j in zip(x, y):

data =  Point(i,j).within(polygon1)
print(data)
if data == False:
    plt.scatter(i,j)
elif data == True:
    break

coord1 = [[8,8], [8,10], [10,10] ,[10,8]]
coord1.append(coord1[0])
xs, ys = zip(*coord1) #create lists of x and y values 
plt.plot(xs,ys)
```